# Describe list of numbers by unique identifier

Tags: c++, algorithm

I think it’s pretty trivial question. I have a system of particles, each has a coordinate. I need to describe every state of the system(i.e. positions of all particles at each time step) by a **number**.

Multiplying them is wrong:

`x1=0 * y1=0 * z1=0 * x2=1 * y2=1 * z2=1 = 0`

and, for example,

`x1=1 * y1=1 * z1=1 * x2=0 * y2=0 * z2=0 = 0`

gives the same result, although it’s different states.

The algorithm below, is a bit better but still wrong

`1*(x1=1 * y1=1 * z1=1) + 2*(x2=0 * y2=0 * z2=0) + ...`

How to convert a **list of number** to unique **number**?

Comment: What's your question? to do some encrypting of that?

Comment: How big of a number? Can you toss the particles into a container and use the index?

Comment: is hashing not a good idea to you?

Comment: @user4581301 tens of thousands

Comment: @Rika, how exactly? The only thing comes to mind is to convert all coordinates to a single string like "x1=0y1=0z1=0..." and then get hash of that string using c++ std hash

Comment: Every time you create a particle assign to it the the lowest free identification number. On destruction you give the number back, or in the case of tens of thousands, you say Smurf it, and just keep counting upward.

Comment: @stark there could be two absolutely equal state at two different points of a time

Comment: @user4581301 but destruction will be called only in the end of program run. I need to get number that describes current state at **every second**

Comment: So the number has to describe the current state an not merely be an abstract identifier?

Comment: @user4581301, say, I want to replay the experiment after it done. To replay, I need to know positions of each particles at every moment of time. During the experiment I can write it directly - in form(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,...), so for each time step I will have a large amount of data to write. Or I can encode it by a single number and then decode, on the program startup

Comment: @user4581301, like, for the first milisecond I will have tens of thousands data to write, for the second milisecond the same... Or I can have a single number for first milisecond, single number for second...

Comment: We have 6 positions and a timestamp that need to be combined in such a way A) the product is unique and B) that you can recover the required information from the number. This number goes into a file. You're better off discarding the concept of a number. What you want top do is store all six numbers and the timestamp and apply lossless compression.

Comment: @user4581301 why 6 positions? And product, You mean like “multiplying”?

Comment: You could also steal a page from video encoding and store the deltas. You can discard the time component if you have a guaranteed time increment.

Comment: I may be reading this wrong but `x1` and `x2` looks like 2 recorded positions for x.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214018/discussion-between-artur-klochko-and-user4581301).

Comment: By product I meant the result of the combination. My apologies for using an overloaded term.

Comment: @user4581301, particle 1 - (x1,y1,z1) ... particle 74732 - (x 74732,y74732,z74732)

Comment: If these positions are integers and don't get too big you can bit-shift and OR to pack them into a larger number.

Comment: I recommend updating/rewriting the question to expand on what you have what you want and your ultimate goal for this number. Harvest what you've added in the comments to help clarify. Someone will have had to implement a system similar to what you really need to do and can provide input and it'll probably be something completely different from what you're thinking of trying. You want a solution to your problem, not a solution for the problems with your proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your system has N elements with (x,y,z) coordinates where each of x,y,z is represented by a double(64-bit), your point probably looks similar to this:

```
struct point { double x, y, z;};
```

The simplest way to express that as a unique "number" is to represent your system as an array of points of size N and interpret its binary representation as number. An array is contiguous in memory so it *is* a number in itself. The easiest way to interpret it as a number is by interpreting its bytes as big integer, where the overall number is computed as

`state[0] + 2^8 *state[1] + 2^16 * state[2] + ... 2^*((n - 1)*8) * state[n-1]`

To compute this you would of course need a bigint library, and it is probably not useful for many purposes. If some numbers repeat often and there a not too many of them this can however already be helpful, since you can start to replace them with simple ids during the first run through the data by aliasing them to a smaller id. For any given run, the size of the id will only have the size of the number of different configurations, plus the overhead to store a translation table from the "number" to the smaller id. Hence this obviously only pays off if configurations repeat.

Why can't you use anything smaller? If you used any smaller value to represent the x,y, and z coordinates, two values would be represented by the same number. The type does not matter here: if your point's were `bool`, you see even more clearly that any smaller value would have to conflate 0 and 1.

A system with (2^64 * 2^64 * 2^64)^N possible states cannot be represented by any fewer bits while still distinguishing each state uniquely.

You can use hashing to make lookup of these states faster if you are not looking at a situation where most of your position in the state space occur. This is however clearly based on a low probability of collisions. The hash just maps your big number to a smaller one in a way that reduces collisions between elements. If you hash, e.g., the contents of the aforementioned point-array, you can look up a certain state, e.g., to increment a count of how many times you have seen it before or add the time-steps at which the state was observed to a list keyed by this hash in a hash map.

You can use lossless compression if your states have an uneven probability distribution to use less memory for the most frequent states. You still need the same worst-case memory, but in a simplified example you would assign 0 to your most probably value, 1 to the next most probably etc. Algorithms to look up here are huffmann coding and LZ/DEFLATE. They are typically readily available through libraries.

Comment: I think it’s the best answer, unless You didn’t explain how exactly to get unique number. Okay, I will get double level array, like `float state[N][3]` and what is the next?

Comment: I have extended my answer to explain this in more detail. Without really knowing what you're trying to do it is hard to help you. The real answer to your question is the usual "well it depends...".

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert a list of number to unique number?

There are various mathematical tricks for this (e.g. leveraging prime factorization), but that does not solve your problem, since the "unique number" is potentially quite large. (The upper bound must be at least the number of possible states.) The number of bits required to store the "unique number" may very well be the same as the sum of the number of bits required to store each number in the list. In that case, even though you call it a single number, it takes the computer just as much work to compute and store it as it would take to store the raw list.

*To put the situation in more familiar terms: pick up a pencil and choose between writing ten thousand 2-digit numbers or a single 20,000-digit number on a sheet of paper. Which option is easier?*

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, to generate a unique number for a 3D point, device a formula  like below

assume 255 is your unique factor and considering your equation

x1=0 * y1=0 * z1=0 * x2=1 * y2=1 * z2=1 = 0

You could yield a unique number by,

```
 UniqueNumber = (255 * x1) + (512 * y1) + 1024 * z1) + (2048 * x2) + (4096* y2) + (8192 * z2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the diferent values (discrete, bounded) of the variables that define the state, the most compact way to encode their state is using the following formula.

Let the cardinalities of each variable be `n0`, `n1`, `n2`, `n3`..., while the variable values are `v0`, `v1`, v2`...  The formula is:

```
v0 + n0*v1 + n0*n1*v2 + n0*n1*n2 * v3 + .... + n0*n1*..*nm-1 * vn
```

if you compare it with the expresion for a number in base B with digits `d0`, `d1`...

```
d0 + B * d1 + B^2 * d2 + B^n-1 * bn-1
```

You will see that the only thing we have *extended* is that the base for each digit is different.

This is applied, for example, to compute in a compact form the number of seconds in a day from the midnight as considering the digits in these sequence of basis:

```
60, 60, 24, 365, 100
ss, mm, hh, jd, c
```

for seconds, minutes, hours, julian days, years, centuries, etc.